# Call Java method in Lambda expression and get the result

Tags: java

I want to use this code to make remote REST API calls.

```
public TransactionsBean transactionProcess(TransactionsBean ro) {

        String tnx_id = ro.getTransaction_id();

        PaymentTransaction transaction = new PaymentTransaction("sale", tnx_id);

        try {
            RestClient client = RestClientBuilder.builder()
                    .gatewayUrl("https://localhost:8443").build();
            Mono<PaymentTransaction> result = client.execute(transaction)
                    .doOnSuccess(
                            response -> parseRawSuccessResponse(response))
                    .doOnError(e -> System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage()));
            result.block(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

        } catch (SSLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return final_obj;
    }

private TransactionsBean parseRawSuccessResponse(PaymentTransaction result) {
        TransactionsBean obj = new TransactionsBean();
        System.out.println("Successfull " + result.getTransactionId());
        obj.setTransaction_id("Sending Successfull: " + result.getTransactionId());
        return obj;
    }
```

How I can call `parseRawSuccessResponse(PaymentTransaction result)` into lambda expression and return the result into `transactionProcess` method?

Comment: You can't do that - `parseRawSuccessResponse` executes asynchronously, after `transactionProcess` has already exited.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Is there a way to restructure the code somehow to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want without breaking asynchronous flow, because the response could be received after the `transactionProcess` method has exited.

Proper way of doing this is to take a callback into your `transactionProcess` method:

```
public void transactionProcess(TransactionsBean ro, Consumer<TransactionsBean> onSuccess) {
    ...
    .doOnSuccess(response -> onSuccess.accept(parseRawSuccessResponse(response)))
    ...
}
```

Callers would invoke it with a lambda of their own:

```
transactionProcess(
    myTxBean
,   tx -> System.out.println("Got response, txId="+tx.getTransactionId())
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I removed result.block(Duration.ofSeconds(30));. It was there just for test. Can you show me please solution with restructured code for parsing the result from lambda expression?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Then you would have to change the signature of your method completely: the caller will pass you his callback to get the transaction once you have it.

Comment: My general idea is to parse the result from doOnSuccess into java method and send it back into transactionProcess(TransactionsBean ro)'s return method.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Like I said in my first comment, you can't.

Comment: Can you extend your code example a little bit? I'm missing some key points?

Comment: @PeterPenzov This is a straightforward way to return values asynchronously: once transaction completes asynchronously inside `transactionProcess`, the callback `tx -> System.out.println(...)` gets invoked. In the meantime, the caller could proceed to doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return from an asynchronous method, but you can block until it finishes.

```
TransactionsBean obj = client.execute(transaction)
    .map(response -> parseRawSuccessResponse(response))
    .block();
```